# Limit of a sum as number of terms approaches ∞

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics

Is it possible to find the limiting value of function at large `N`?

```
f[N_] = Sum[Binomial[0.5*(N) - 1, a]*
            Binomial[0.5*(N) - 1, a - 1]*0.5*.7^1 * .3^(N - a - 1), {a, 2, N, 2}]
```

I expect it to behave as a Gaussian at large `N`.

Comment: Never use capital letters as variable names! Especially `N`, as this is a reserved symbol in _Mathematica_. For figuring out a limit, there is... `Limit`! Also in this case, try using exact numbers (1/2, 7/10 etc.) as there may exist an exact expression. Using 0.5 etc. forces Mathematica to use numric, non-exact methods.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: I think you have a problem with your expression... half your terms (for `a > n/2`) will be equal to zero...

Answer (score 4):

With `N` replaced by `n` and exact numbers, the function in the Question can be written as

```
f[n_] = Sum[Binomial[n/2 - 1, a]*Binomial[n/2 - 1, a - 1]*(7/20)*(3/10)^(n - a - 1), 
  {a, 2, n, 2}]
```

Although Mathematica can perform the `Sum`, the result in terms of `HypergeometricPFQ` is not particularly enlightening.  Instead, plot `f[n]`.

```
ListLogPlot[Table[f[n], {n, 40}], AxesLabel -> {n, f}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Clearly, `f` varies as `c1 Exp[-c2 n]` for large `n`.  The constants can be obtained from

```
FindFit[Table[{n, N[f[n]] // Chop}, {n, 15, 40}], c1 Exp[-c2 n], {c1, c2}, n]
(* {c1 -> 0.0333327, c2 -> 0.183299} *)
```